# Object reference not set while registering bot

Tags: botframework

I created a simple Bot and its working fine in bot emulator.

I published this Bot into Microsoft azure and trying to registering my Bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework.

I am getting the following error.

object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: You published it to azure. Did you set your end point correctly? Can you share more details ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that all of the url include the HTTPS scheme.  Eg:  https://yourbot.azurewebsites.net,
https://www.somesite.com,
etc.

See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1027#event-760233371).